# Flex locale files in multiple directories

Tags: apache-flex, localization, locale

I have a "locale" folder in my project where I store my localization files. Can I use multiple folders? One would be Project/locale, other would be Project/src/Something/locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.
Just add source folder path at "Flex Build Path" (Right click on your project ->properties)

Add Folder for your example: `locale\{locale}` and `src\Something\locale\{locale}`

But be careful that locale file names cannot be the same under these two paths.